# CMake slow with large projects

Tags: cmake, fortran

I have over a thousand Fortran and a dozen C source files which compile into a single executable (FHI-aims). The code is full of interdependencies making it difficult to break it up into auxiliary libraries. For some reason dependency scanning is slow - it takes over 10 seconds to report that no files have been modified. With a single Makefile that time is about 2 seconds. I'm using ifort and icc. I could upload my depend.make (2.0 M) if that's of help.

Is there anything I could try to speed up dependency scanning? Is this normal? With `VERBOSE=1` I see that it's constantly entering and exiting the build directory reporting that everything is up to date.

Comment: The makefile which is generated by CMake is slow, right? That would be a known issue. Ninja-build and other projects try to tackle this, but not for Fortran. One of the CMake developers is currently trying to extend Ninja accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it's the CMake makefile. Dividing the code into auxiliary libraries would help as long as there are no changes in the .mod files.